# Exiting Multi-Step Access VBA Macro on Error but Continue Code that called the Macro

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a macro that calls 4 functions one after the other.

The macro is called like this:

```
For Each APP In sArr
    DoCmd.RunMacro ("doMacro")
Next
```

If the macro fails at its first function, I want to exit the function, exit the macro but continue the for loop above.

I tried **Exit Function**, but it exits the function and continues the macro.
I tried **End** but that stops all code execution, which is not what I want.

How would I exit the macro but continue the for loop?

Comment: you should probably post the entire 'doMacro' macro and also show how you implemented Exit Function and end.

Comment: It looks like you're looking for a way to handle run-time errors. Would you like to insert an `On Error` statement?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the `RunMacro` statement with `On Error` statements - `Resume Next` to turn off error handling, `GoTo 0` to restore it:

```
For Each APP In sArr
    On Error Resume Next
        DoCmd.RunMacro "doMacro"
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            'assuming APP has a Name property:
            "Macro 'doMacro' failed in " & APP.Name & ": " & Err.Description
        End If
    On Error GoTo 0
Next
```

Comment: Tried this but one of the funcitons in the macro still produces a run-time error, which halts execution and forces me to end.